# jquery ajax results with div sliding down

Tags: jquery, ajax, slidedown

I have a page with a dropdown of all the users. when a person selects someone in the dropdown i fire off an ajax call to get user's information. that all works fine.  I am trying to display the results of the ajax call in a div that slides down all pretty like.

i tried this:

```
 function getInfo(id)
{
        $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "users/userInfo.php",
                   data: "userId=" + id,
                   success: function(result){
                     $("#userData").html(result);
                   }
                 });
 $("#userData").hide();
 $("#userData").slideDown('slow');
 };
```

and on the first selection a person makes, it doesn't slide, it just appears.  however if the person were to select a different option, the slide works perfectly.  how can i get that first ajax response to slide?

i added the .hide() because i read that it has to be hidden in order to slide.  I tried animate() and that was a disaster...

Comment: Hide, append, and slide down in the ajax success function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to rearrange your calls. move `hide` to before the ajax call. Then move `slidedown` to inside of the success callback:

```
function getInfo(id)
{
    $("#userData").hide();
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "users/userInfo.php",
            data: {userId: id},
            success: function(result){
                $("#userData")
                    .html(result)
                    .slideDown('slow');
        }
    });
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the two functions `hide` and then `slidedown` in the ajax call on my homepage for navigation but were not successful.
[Here](http://konzertagentur-koerner.de) is my website, when you click on download you see that it works only the first time. When you click again, it will be hidden.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/timokoerner/6311756) is my js, I hope you can give me a hint.

I enclose the js function that is called when clicking download:

```
function download( ) {

//$('#download').hide();

$.post(ajfile+'download', function(res) {

    $(".container").css("display","none");

    $('#download').html(res);
});
```

}

I enclose the php code to call the js with the links:

```
<div id="header" >  

    <ul id="navigation">

    <?php 
    # links
    foreach ($nav as $nav2) {

        echo '<li><a href="#'.lcfirst($nav2).'">'.$voc[$nav2].' ( ';

        # ü not possible as dec value
        if ($nav2== 'Aboutus')
            echo 'u';

        else
            echo lcfirst(substr( $voc[$nav2],0,1));

        echo ' ) </a></li>';

    } ?>

    </ul>   
    <input type=button onclick=download() value=Download(l)>
</div>
```

[Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-keypress-navigation-using-jquery/) is the tutorial I used which demonstrates how to create a website using keypress and links.

Basically I use a `href` attribute inside a `a` tag as navigation link. Moreover, I have a keypressed listener event. So everytime the link is clicked or a key pressed, the div with the id is called showing the content. The rest of the content is hidden with js `css()` method.